# Fail2ban detects attempts from permanently banned IPs

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I have a VM with a custom firewall script and Fail2ban.

I've identified some IP ranges that make permanent intrusion attempts so I blocked them directly in my firewall script. Here is a simplified overview:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     Custom firewall
# Required-Start:   $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short Description:    Firewall init script
# Description:      Custom firewall
### END INIT INFO

## Lock everything
# Clear current tables
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t filter -X 

# Deny all connexions (input and output)
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP


## Common configurations
# Preserve established connexions
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP (ping)
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT


## Custom rules
# SSH
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# HTTP
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

## JAIL
iptables -A INPUT -s 61.147.80.0/24 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s 61.167.49.0/24 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s 61.174.50.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 61.174.51.0/24 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s 103.41.124.0/24 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s 122.225.97.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 122.225.103.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 122.225.109.0/24 -j DROP
```

Fail2ban works like a charm but I'm surprised that it still detects attempts from banned IPs such as `122.225.109.107` since they should be banned with my firewall script. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packets go through iptables rules in the order in which the rules appear.

You are banning the mentionned ips at the end of the ruleset, and before that banning, you accept all traffic to port 80 and ssh 22. So your banning rules do not catch.

You should let fail2ban manage the banning, as he puts the banning rules at the beginning of the iptables ruleset, or put your banning rules at the beginning of your script with commands like `iptables -I INPUT 1 rule` to place a rule before the first rule in the set.

And as you have a default policy of DROP, there is no use to put rules with DROP target at the end of the ruleset.

Comment: Thank you :). I will use `iptables -I INPUT 1 rule`. The main goal of this is to avoid emails from fail2ban for those IP ranges.